# Application indicators don't seem to have tooltips -- is this due to conformity to touch interfaces?

Tags: 11.04, indicator, ayatana, usability, touchscreen

I very much liked the weather details showing up simply by way of mouse over the weather icon of the datetime applet. (The indicator-weather shows similar infos only via click, currently as menu items that can't be clicked but are highlighted as if ...)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [reason given for this](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/CustomStatusMenuDesignGuidelines#What%20about%20tooltips?) is more for consistency between different applications:

> Status menus do not have tooltips. This is for consistency of behavior: most menus have never needed tooltips, so it is most consistent if all menus are designed to not need them, rather than some menus having them and some not.

This is a relatively contentious issue, with 208 people having marked [a bug requesting the reintroduction of these tooltips](https://bugs.launchpad.net/indicator-application/+bug/527458) as affecting them.